# Echo HTML tag problems with quotes

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put quotes in the php that handles the `select` tag. I need that the `select` tag displays the result of the query that is inside. How can I do this correctly?

```
<?php 
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `metlab`.`cutlog_junta` WHERE `finalizado` = 0")or die (mysql_error());
    $idtimeleft= 0;
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        $idtimeleft++;                      
        $idprueba = $array[0];
        $id_log = $array["id_log"];
        $id_operador = $array["id_operador"];
        $started = $array["started"];
        $finished = $array["finished"];
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
        $tiempo1 = new DateTime('now');
        $tiempo2 = new DateTime($finished);
        if ($tiempo1 < $tiempo2){
        $tiemporestante = date_diff($tiempo2,$tiempo1 );
        $timeleft = $tiemporestante->format("%h:%i:%s");
        }else{
        $timeleft = "00:00:00";
        }                       
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT r.job AS JOB,p.heat_code AS HEAT_CODE,p.probeta AS PROBETA,p.id_line AS ID_LINE,p.id_box_pin AS ID_BOX_PIN,p.id_conexion AS ID_CONEXION
                            FROM metlab.prueba_junta p
                            INNER JOIN metlab.requerimientos_junta r ON p.id_job=r.id WHERE p.id='".$id_log."'")or die (mysql_error());
        $mhs = mysql_fetch_array($sql);                     
        echo (" <tr id='row". $idtimeleft ."'>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td>
                    <td>" . $id_log . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['JOB'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['ID_BOX_PIN'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['ID_CONEXION'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['HEAT_CODE'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['PROBETA'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $mhs['ID_LINE'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $started . "</td>                           
                    <td><div id='idtimeleft" . $idtimeleft ."'>" . $timeleft . "</div></td>
                    <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cut_process'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin'></i>CUT</button>
                            <div id='cut_process' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                    <button type='button'class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class='modal-title'>CUT PROCESS</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <input type='text' placeholder='INSERT COMMENT' class='form-control'><br>
                                        <label>Supervisor:</label>
                                        <select class='btn btn-primary'>
                                            <?php //////////////////////////////problem
                                            $query='SELECT nombre
                                            FROM metlab.supervisores';
                                            $result1=mysql_query($query);
                                            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
                                            <option><?php echo $row1[0];?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php endwhile;?>
                                        </select> /////////////////////////////end problem
                                    </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i>SEND COMMENT</button>
                                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#milling_process'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin'></i>MILLING</button>
                            <div id='milling_process' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                    <button type='button'class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class='modal-title'>MILLING PROCESS</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <input type='text' placeholder='INSERT COMMENT' class='form-control'>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i>SEND COMMENT</button>
                                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#rectified_process'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin'></i>RECTIFIED</button>
                            <div id='rectified_process' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                    <button type='button'class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class='modal-title'>RECTIFIED PROCESS</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <input type='text' placeholder='INSERT COMMENT' class='form-control'>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i>SEND COMMENT</button>
                                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#machined_process'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin'></i>MACHINED</button>
                            <div id='machined_process' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                    <button type='button'class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class='modal-title'>MACHINED PROCESS</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <input type='text' placeholder='INSERT COMMENT' class='form-control'>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i>SEND COMMENT</button>
                                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>" . $finished . "</td>
                    <td>" .  $idprueba . "</td>
                </tr>");    
                                        
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: At the `problem` lines you are already in PHP. Leave the string with a closing double quote close the echo with a `;`, run the PHP, then begin another `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write directly HTML code inside the page avoiding PHP echo function.

In this example you use PHP short tag only when you need it:

```
<tr id="row<?=$idtimeleft?>">
```

And when you need to perform some action you just open PHP tag and write your code.

```
<select>
<?php
$query='SELECT nombre FROM metlab.supervisores';
$result1=mysql_query($query);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)):
?>
<option><?=$row1[0]?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

You don't need semicolon after "while(...):"

Anyway you should read something about Twig to use template engine to write cleaner code.
Bye!!